# Proving Group of Odd Order cannot be Doubly Transitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, permutations, finite-groups, alternative-proof

I found the claim in a an article , here is my proof attempt:

Let $G$ be a primitive group (transitive) on a set $\Omega$ of $n$ elements.

By the definition of [doubly transitive](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Doubly_transitive_group_action), there exists an element $g \in G$ such that $(a, b)^g = (c, d)$ where distinct $a, b,c,d \in \Omega$.

Since there are $n(n-1)$ distinct $(a, b)$ tuples, if we assign an element/permutation of $G$ to each distinct $(a, b)$ tuple satisfying the definition of doubly transitive, there should be $n(n-1)$ elements in $G$, but $n(n-1)$ is even, thus we prove the claim.

Is this proof correct? Is there an alternative proof?

Comment: *NB:* "can not" means something different than "cannot".

Comment: @Shaun I have edited, what about the proof? is it correct?

Comment: I don't know much a doubly transitive groups. Perhaps you could state the definition . . .

Comment: @Shaun here is the definition: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Doubly_transitive_group_action

Comment: Why does assigning an element of $G$ to each permutation of ordered pairs exhaust all of the elements of $G$?  (In other words, can't multiple elements of $G$ permute one specific ordered pair to another specific ordered pair?)  Because if it doesn't, then you can't use this technique to assure yourself that you have actually determined $\vert G \vert$.

Comment: Your definition of doubly transitive is not quite right. You don't need all of $a,b,c,d$ to be distinct, you only need $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$. But you could have $a=c$, for instance.

Comment: And the collection you've obtained need not be a subgroup, so $n(n-1)$ need not divide $|G|$ (meaning, you haven't established that yet). For example, if you take $S_4$ which is doubly transitive (in fact, it is faithfully $4$-transitive on $\{1,2,3,4\}$), you could pick $(3,4)$ as the element that maps $1,2$ to itself, so that you didn't even pick up the identity element.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see point in your and Robert Shore's comment, but that is what i managed to do so far i am still working....

Answer (score 1):

Proceed by contradiction and assume $(G,\cdot)$ is a doubly transitive permutation group on $\Omega$ but $2\nmid|G|$ where $|\Omega|>1$. By the double transitivity of $G$ we may fix  distinct $a,b\in\Omega$ and $\pi\in G$ such that $\pi(a)=b$ and $\pi(b)=a$. But $(a\;b)$ is a $\pi$ cauchy cycle and thus Ruffini's theorem guarantees $2\mid\text{ord}(\pi)$ which in turn implies $2\mid|G|$ via Lagrange's theorem. $\it{reductio\;ad\;absurdum}$.

Comment: I don't understand the fixing of   distinct $a,b\in\Omega$ and $\pi\in G$ such that $\pi(a)=b$ and $\pi(b)=b$... fixing means and $\pi(a)=a$, isn't it?

Comment: @MRJames2017. $(a,b)^{\pi}=(b,a)$...using your notation.

Comment: @MRJames2017. To fix distinct $a,b\in\Omega$ is simply to declare $a,b$ different constants in $\Omega$ but not variables. When $\pi(x)=x$ then we say "$\pi$ $\it{fixes}$ $x$" or "$x$ is a $\it{fixed\;point}$ of $\pi$".

Comment: That is okay but we are dealing with  ordered tuples, where $(a,b) \neq (b,a)$ (definition of transitive group: given any two ordered tuples each having a pair of distinct elements, there is a group element taking one ordered tuple to the other.), I don't see how you can write $(a,b)^{\pi}=(b,a)$ as fixing of $(a,b)$, can you refer me to any book chapter or online  document describing similar things?

Comment: @MRJames2017. Nowhere did I write what you claim. Reread what I wrote carefully and  be formal in your objections so that you can find your point of misunderstanding and resolve it. The term "fixed point" is found easily in any google search. To fix an element is NOT the same as declaring it a fixed point of some function. Two DIFFERENT forms of jargon. Again, a simple internet search, using the phrase in the search bar should help.

Comment: @MRJames2017. The definition of double transitivity on $\Omega$ is as follows : A permutation group $(G,\cdot)$ is double transitive on $\Omega$ iff given $(a,b),(c,d)\in\Omega\times\Omega$ there exists $\pi\in G$ such that $\pi(a)=c$ and $\pi(b)=d$ where $a\neq b$ and $c\neq d$.

Comment: I am not familiar with Ruffini's theorem, plz provide necessary link or state the full theorem so I can look into.

Comment: @MRJames2017. I think you know you can find that kind information through a simple google search as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @MRJames2017. Ruffini's theorem simply states that the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of its cauchy cycle lengths.

Comment: when you write  $2\mid|G|$ via Lagrange's theorem, it measns you have a subgroup of order $2$, how you get that information from "..$\pi$ cauchy cycle and thus Ruffini's theorem guarantees $2\mid\text{ord}(\pi)$"

Comment: @MRJames2017. $2\mid\text{ord}(\pi)=|\langle\pi\rangle|$.